# Get Infopath Xml Form Views using Rest Api

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-rest-api, forms-library

I am basically trying to retrieve all the views configured inside an InfoPath XML form.

For example:

I have created 2 views in an InfoPath form. One is basically the Default View and One is a Read Only view.

What I want to achieve here is to use REST API to retrieve the XML form from the Forms library and the views in the retrieved form.

Not sure if this is possible but if someone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to download the XML file in forms library or just to retrieve and read it?

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing it, but it sounds like you want the content of the form itself?

But you could also be looking to get the actual form?

If you are looking to get the content from the form submission you should be able to use the URL:

```
https://YOUR_SHAREPOINT_WEBSITE/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('LISTNAME')/Items
```

This will return it in XML, but you can also run this through Java or Excel depending on your needs.

Comment: How about the form itself?