# Interacting with Forms Library using the REST API

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-rest-api, forms-library

I am looking to fetch forms from the Forms Library and use them in an external application. I see a REST API for Documents Library, but I have not found any discussion of interacting with the forms in a Forms Library using this API.

[This answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270021/get-infopath-xml-form-views-using-rest-api) mentions getting form submissions, and mentions getting at the form itself but the question wasn't clear so the answerer did not cover getting the form itself, only submissions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below query to get the form library data :

```
http://server/qa/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={***E885}&XMLDATA=TRUE&noredirect=true
```

Reference URL :

https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/the-form-cannot-run-the-specified-query-in-infopath-2007-forms-migrated-to-sharepoint-2010/#comment-564